# HTML/CSS - How to display transparent text snippet at end of input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, field

In this picture from the google calculators input you can see the right side parantheses not placed, but marked, I wonder how I can place a gray-transparent string in at the end of an input field in HTML?

[image]

Comment: Wrap string in tag, use CSS with `rgba` or `opacity`.

Comment: @elclanrs Last I checked, you couldn't do that _within_ an input of type text, which it seems is what this user wants.

Comment: @Daedalus: I didn't understand. I see, I think what OP wants is some sort of "masking" functionality...

Comment: I've tried to make a span next to it and make the span text float over the input, but the span text can be focused

Comment: @Mich' check answer for working demo.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using `div` instead of `input` box.

And give the `div` appear like a textbox.

### HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='start'>(((((((((((</div>
    <div id='end'>)))))))))))</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    display: inline-block;
}
#start {
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#end {
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Output [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKysJ/).

---

To make the div's editable; you can use the `contenteditable` boolean values. Here's how the HTML will look:

```
<div id='container' contenteditable>
    <div id='start'>(((((((((((</div>
    <div id='end' contenteditable="false">)))))))))))</div>
</div>
```

And another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKysJ/1/).

Comment: yeah, but the black text have to be editable, but not the gray

Comment: It still does not work; text can be added after the closing brackets, and they can be deleted as a block.

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you have to use the contenteditable attribut and a little bit of Javascript :

```
<div style="text-align: right; font: 20px Arial; outline: none; border: 1px solid #BBB; padding: 5px;" contenteditable="true">
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].onkeypress = function(e){
        if (e.which == 40){
            this.innerHTML = '(<span style="color: #CCC">)</span>';
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I hope I could help you.

Comment: nice, but the parantheses don't show up and it cant be edited??

Answer (score -1):

Here is working example of what you need..

**html**

```
<div class="input">
    <p class="text"></p>
    <p class="extra"></p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("div.input").click(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e){
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            $("div.input .text").append(char);
            if(e.keyCode==40)   {
              $("div.input .extra").append("<span class='gray'>)</span>");
            }
             if(e.keyCode==41)   {
              $("div.input .extra").text("");
            }
    });
  });
});
```

**css**

```
.input{

width:500px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid black;

}


.gray{
 color:#CCCCCC;
}
p{
display:inline;}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NIkhar/BrMXA/)